# Visual Studio / TFS Api to work with test explorer / cyclomatic complexity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I want to write a small app that integrates with Visual Studio or TFS.
I want to be able to run cyclomatic complexity and/or C# unit tests through my app and then push the result to excel.
Google gave me [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) but it does not help me.

My questions:
1. Is this possible? (API integration part)
2. If so, what APi can I use to accomplish this.

p.s I have not started with a project so I dont have sample code. I want to do an initial investigation to make sure it worth a try.

I know there is a few projects out there that does this but I want to create my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On TFS side, if you want to run unit tests, you need to create a build definition, and add VS build and VS test tasks in the build definition, so, you need to refer `create a build definition` API from website below, and specify the tasks in the api:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#create-a-build-definition

Add an example of create a build definition with rest api for your reference:

```
POST http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=3.2

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "myDefinition",
  "type": "build",
  "quality": "definition",
  "queue": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Build solution **\\*.sln",
      "task": {
        "id": "71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "solution": "**\\*.sln",
        "msbuildArgs": "",
        "platform": "$(platform)",
        "configuration": "$(config)",
        "clean": "false",
        "restoreNugetPackages": "true",
        "vsLocationMethod": "version",
        "vsVersion": "latest",
        "vsLocation": "",
        "msbuildLocationMethod": "version",
        "msbuildVersion": "latest",
        "msbuildArchitecture": "x86",
        "msbuildLocation": "",
        "logProjectEvents": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Test Assemblies **\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
      "task": {
        "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "testAssembly": "**\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
        "testFiltercriteria": "",
        "runSettingsFile": "",
        "codeCoverageEnabled": "true",
        "otherConsoleOptions": "",
        "vsTestVersion": "14.0",
        "pathtoCustomTestAdapters": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "id": "278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249",
    "type": "tfsgit",
    "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
    "localPath": "$(sys.sourceFolder)/MyGitProject",
    "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
    "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
    "clean": "false"
  },
  "options": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "definition": {
        "id": "7c555368-ca64-4199-add6-9ebaf0b0137d"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "parallel": "false",
        "multipliers": "[\"config\",\"platform\"]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "forceClean": {
      "value": "false",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "config": {
      "value": "debug, release",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "platform": {
      "value": "any cpu",
      "allowOverride": true
    }
  },
  "triggers": [],
  "comment": "my first definition"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Cece Dong you need to run your tests as part of a build definition.
I assume your app will always trigger the same build definition? So I personally would create the build definition in TFS and then Queue this definition.  Once you have your definition created you can queue a build of it as described in the API here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build

When running tests you can specify the Test Run Title by which you can later on identify "your" tests.  The test management is described in the API docs here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/overview
You can fetch your test runs and the cases within those tests and create files in whatever format you need them in.

I know you said you want to create your own application and not use something existing, but in case you would need some code samples you could look at the following build tasks, as they are open source and you could see how certain things were implemented:
- [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) (Allows you to queue new builds)
- [Testrun Perfromance Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.test-run-performance-analyzer&targetId=12d83491-05ec-4d25-9701-6ee9a0e83256&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) (Will fetch the last n TestRuns and creates CSV files for you)
- [tfsrestservice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tfsrestservice) (service that abstracts REST API calls to TFS/VSTS - both tasks mentioned above are based on this)

So I think it is definetly possible to achieve this. The two links pointing to the REST API documentation should help you in order to achieve it.
If you need inspiration I think the tfsrestservice might be helpful to really see what calls are made to the api in order to receive test runs and test cases.

I hope I could help.